# Is changing a WCF data member to nullable a breaking change?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I have a WCF Service that is called by the client.

If my current data contract for the return value is:

```
[Serializable]
[DataContract]
public class StatisticsDto
{
    [DataMember]
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
}
```

and I change only the server implementation to:

```
[Serializable]
[DataContract]
public class StatisticsDto
{
    [DataMember]
    public int? EmployeeId { get; set; }
}
```

does this result in incompatibility until I update the client? or is the value automatically cast to int unless it is null?

Comment: yes, it is...client side cannot deserialize `null` ... but as long as you don't send null there shouldn't be problem ... of course it may depends on used Message serializer

Answer (score 0):

Agree with commenter @Selvin. It is certainly a breaking change for the client until you update the client to handle null values in `EmployeeId` field.